# Xaml Button is "clicked" if it's pressed-and-hold on a touch screen

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, touch, uwp-xaml

I am developing a Windows UWP App with C++. I want to add a button that can either be left-clicked or right-clicked and do corresponding task.

The button works perfectly on normal devices with mouse. Unfortunately on touch screen, if users press-and-hold the button, both left-click and right-click events are triggered.

I am using "Click" to handle the left click event and "RightTapped" to handle the right click event. Any suggestion on how to disable the left-click event when users press-and-hold the button? Thank you!

The XAML code is short:

```
<Button x:Name="m_NewPageButton"
    Content="New Page"
    Height="48"
    Width="199"
    Click="OnClick"
    RightTapped="OnRightClick"/>
```

And here's the cpp code:

```
void MainPage::OnClick()
{
    // Left click task
}

void MainPage::OnRightClick()
{
    // Right click task
}
```

Edit:

Thanks guys, the solution is to change the left click handler to , which will not be triggered by press-and-hold.

Comment: *"Any suggestion on how to disable the left-click event when users press-and-hold the button?"* - That would require a time machine.

Comment: If I remember, the `Tapped` is not fired when the button is held so you could try that instead of the `Click` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hacky but works...

```
    private bool rightClicked;

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rightClicked)
            return;

        await new MessageDialog("left").ShowAsync();
    }

    private async void Button_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        rightClicked = true;
        await new MessageDialog("right").ShowAsync();
        rightClicked = false;
    }
```

I'm guessing this is a flaw in the design.. :(

**Actually... If you use the button's Tapped and RightTapped events it works as it should.  So in this case just replace Clicked with Tapped and all is well... Then you can ignore the hack I put above.**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Holding event to detect a tap and hold. Use the Tapped event for a single tap (or click). The Tapped event should only fire for touch on a quick tap and release. The mouse specific click will raise Tapped but a touch tap-and-hold will not.

Comment: That's not what the OP is after. They want the initial `Click` event ignored (in the past), when the `RightTapped` event is triggered (in the future).

Comment: You could just replace Clicked with RightTapped in XAML if you want to replace click with right tapped.